# alignment issue with div and image

Tags: css, html

I've the below html code with divs as column creators and separators, here when i run this in my web browser, it is creating an overlapping of data or the columns are not getting properly aligned. here actually i want a 3 column layout where in there would be an image in the first and second column top part. you can find the document how it should look like [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/158400822/page3-pdf) and the fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FPWea/). and also i don't want to use table here, just divs should do it. please let me know where am i going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
div.columns  
     { 
width: 508.326px; 
height:709.268px;

}


div.left    {
    width:341px;
    height:709.268px;

border-right:dotted;
float: left;
}


div.right    {
    width:167px;
    height:709.268px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }


div.white
 {

width:188px; 
float:left;
height:436.86px;
    }




div.grey   
       { 
width:188px; 
float:right;
height:436.86px;
}


div.red          
 { 
width:217px;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>
<div class="columns">


<div class="left">

<div class="image">
<img src="../Magazines/Images/Images.jpg" height="380" width="380"/>
</div>

    <div class="white" >The English historian Lord Acton
famously said the “issue which has
swept down the centuries and which
will have to be fought sooner or later is
the people versus the banks”.
This cannot ring truer than now, with
many banks, particularly the biggest
ones, in the public spotlight facing
a wide range of investigations and
litigations, following the 2007-2008
global financial crisis. And as Mr.
Longo puts it, that is all just part of
doing business at the moment if you
are a financial institution such as
Deutsche Bank.
“Since the GFC (global financial
crisis), the industry has gone through
tremendous change on a variety of
fronts,” he tells Hong Kong Lawyer
one grayish morning last month in
Thomson Reuters’ office in Central.
“So we have to deal with investigations
and litigations on the one hand, and
on the other hand adapt our model
to see how we can reorganise and
restructure the institution to comply
with the variety of regulatory changes
as well as develop existing and new
business opportunities to replace
income streams that are no longer
viable.” </div>
<div class="grey">And to make it even more challenging,
a grayish macro-economic backdrop
where the economy remains weak in
Europe while recovering slowly in the
US.
“There are also challenges driven by the
plethora of reforms coming out of the
G20 commitments and demographics
and urbanisation, a whole range of
things… It is an interesting time to be in
banking,” he says with a laugh. The 53
year old should know, given that he was
once a key member of the Australian
Securities and Investments Commission,
responsible for enforcement.
The way that Mr. Longo sees it, how
the universal banking model changes
following the crisis will dictate the
future of banking. For instance, a key
discussion has been whether retail
banking activity should be separated
from trading and investment banking
activity.
“It’s a Glass-Steagall-type discussion,”
he continues, referring to the US
Banking Act of 1933, which separated
commercial and investment banking
components. It was passed during the
Great Depression in the 1930s. Sections
of it were repealed in 1999 partly to</div>
  </div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="red" >allow for the merger of retail banks
and investment banks that engage in
underwriting and dealing in securities
as banking operations.
“Some people argue that if we want to
protect the public purse, we need to get
so called ‘ risky’ investment banking
activity away from deposit-taking
activity that is seen as a public good.
That doesn’t seem to be happening in
the US, while that is happening in the
UK, with continued questioning in the
rest of Europe, generally, about whether
to do that.”
Before and after the GFC
The main difference before and after the
crisis, says Mr. Longo, is growth.
“Everybody was growing, hiring, legal
departments were growing,” he recalls.
“Since the crisis, there have been
enormous changes in how we think
about (things like) headcount,
resources, cost efficiency , adapting to
a new environment… Managing in that
environment is different from managing
in an environment where there is lots of
growth, hiring, and all of that.”
For instance, while he used to spend
more time on banking transactions in
the early days after joining Deutsche
Bank in 2002, Mr. Longo now often
finds himself dealing with managing a
range of regulatory issues and strategy .
Lawyers thinking of going in-house in a
bank now can also expect to deal with
a huge increase in regulatory work “to
develop responses to, and implement,
the immense amount of new global
bank and financial institution reforms”,
he says. These include “responding to
Dodd-Frank (Act) and Volcker (Rules)
from the US, the European Market
Infrastructure Regulation (EMIR), Living
Wills and Resolution plans, and the OTC
(over-the-counter) derivative reforms
and central clearing initiatives”.</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: copy to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi @Roar, thanks for responding. i have given the fiddle link in my question, you can find here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPWea/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/FPWea/6/) and let me know if this is what you want.

I have made the following changes:

1. In your CSS the width of the left section was smaller than the sum of what was set for the white and grey divs and this was making the grey div to wrap-around (which is fall below). This was making your text overlap. Remember that the sum of the widths of the inner divs must be less than that of the container div for them to be displayed properly.
2. For your case we can split them just by using `display: inline-block;` rule itself and hence I have avoided the `float` rule settings. If you want to stick with floats, you can check this [**version**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/fnTJm/).
3. I have rounded off the height setting to the nearest whole number just for example. You can modify this as required.

   ```
    div.columns {
       width: 670px;
       height:710px;
    }
    div.left {
       width:440px;
       height:710px;
       border-right:dotted;
       display: inline-block;
    }
    div.right {
       width:210px;
       height:710px;
       display: inline-block;
       margin-left: 10px;
    }
    div.white {
       width:215px;
       height:100%;
       border-right:dotted;
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: top;
    }
    div.grey {
       width:215px;
       height:100%;
       display: inline-block;
    }
    .image {
       height: 390px;
       width: 100%;
    }
   ```

Comment: Hi @Harry thanks for the solution, this is what i was looking for, but if you see the dotted borders by scrolling down, it is only displaying half for one and more than the text limit for other, also can you please extend the image width a bit so that, it's span would be exactly ending just a cm before the second dotted line. Thanks again

Comment: @user2423959 ah the borders, that is the problem in specifying the borders using divs, if the height of the div changes they also change (small/more). I have addressed that in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/FPWea/8/) by assigning a min height. For the Image, you can see in the fiddle that I changed the Image Div to match your needs but I wouldn't recommend increasing the width of image because that might cause a stretched appearance sometimes. This code would align it in center. If you have any more questions, let me know. Else, please consider accepting the answer ;)

Comment: Thank you very much @Harry. this is fine now. Thanks again.